# How to setup Firebase for Flutter web

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web

I'm trying to make a web version of my Flutter Firebase app Please Help!!!
This my current config which doesn't work

```js
     var firebase = require("firebase/app");
     var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "xxxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxxxxx.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        appId: "1:xxxxxxxxxx:web:xxxxxxx",
        measurementId: "XXXXXXXXX"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
```

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: Where did you place those configurations? Which frontend framework are you using? Where are you deploying your project to?

Comment: I do config in index.html, Front end Android, iOS, Web. I deploy my project in Localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to create a new project when migrating to web
 1. run this command in the terminal

```
flutter channel dev
```

2. upgrade flutter with

```
flutter upgrade
```

3. create a project

```
flutter create web_proj //or anything
```

4. add the necessary script tags in the index.html its inside your Web folder

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

5. add the config inside index.html also

```
<script>
        var firebase = require("firebase/app");
     var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "xxxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxxxxx.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        appId: "1:xxxxxxxxxx:web:xxxxxxx",
        measurementId: "XXXXXXXXX"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
</script>
```

6. add the dependencies like firestore,and others and enjoy

```
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase#-readme-tab-
```

Comment: I recreated the project by running

Comment: flutter create .

Comment: Im using firestore in my app, is there any different firestore dependencies for mobile and web